# Unable to add Parse using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods, bridging-header

Following are the steps I did to add `Parse` using `CocoaPods` but still getting unresolved error.

Added Pods File:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'Parse'

target 'GroomCal' do

end

target 'GroomCalTests' do

end

target 'GroomCalUITests' do

end
```

After that I did `pod install`. Parse and Bolts frameworks got installed (I can see them in XCode).

I then added -Bridging-Header.h and added `#import <Parse/Parse.h>`to it.

[image]

When I try to `import Parse` in `AppDelegate.swift` file, I still get `No such Module Parse` error message. What am I missing here.

[image]

I did use the `*.xcworkspace` file to open the project too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use cocoapods with swift you need to add the flag 
`use_frameworks!` to the podfile as swift doesn't allow to add static libraries.

source [Cocoapods blog](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/)

Comment: Does it matter where I add it in the podfile? Right after the `platform :ios, '8.0'` line is ok?

Comment: That is the most common place.

Comment: Hurray that worked! thanks, wish `Parse` added that to their documentation (most of their documentation is so great), thank you agian.